# Debug on cloud foudry with IntelliJ

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, cloud-foundry

Does anyone of you has already tried to remote-debug an app running in Cloud Foundry using IntelliJ?
What is the setup?

Comment: That is what unit tests, and integration tests are. You should test your app end-to-end, make sure it works they you want it, as standalone. Only then deploy to cloud foundry.

Answer (score 2):

- You should Add to your manifest.yml the following:

  ```
  env:
     JBP_CONFIG_DEBUG: '{enabled: true}'
  ```
- Push the application
- Open The project in IntelliJ IDE
- Open the run configuration

Click on + button and add Remote configuration 
(Transport should be "socket" & and debugger mode should be "Attach")

```
Host: localhost
Port: 8000
```

Note: Verify that for debug entries you have the following entry

```
env:
  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000
```

- Click and apply and close the window.
- Open the Terminal to set up SSH tunnel for debug framework
- Put the following command in the CLI

> cf ssh -N -T -L 8000:localhost:8000 myapp

Put a BP at your code and click on the debug button

You should see the following in the debug tab (the debug socket is connected)

```
  Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8000', transport: 'socket'
```

- Run the application URL in the browser and it should stop in your
  breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already tried this and did not work.
So few questions :
1. "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000" shall be in the the Intellij Run/Debug Configuration right ?
2. The command "cf ssh -N -T -L 8000:localhost:8000 myapp" give:
FAILED
Error opening SSH connection: dial tcp 52.72.74.186:2222: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Comment: 1. yes 2. are you able to run ssh command to your app from the CMD ? does your space is ssh enabled "cf ssh-enabled" , does you use Diego ? I use the steps I provided very often and it works from Eclipse and Intellij ...

Comment: Does it helps ? did you able to debug your app?